# socket python : recvfrom

Tags: python, sockets, recvfrom

I would like to know if socket.recvfrom in python is a blocking function ? I couldn't find my answer in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom)
If it isn't, what will be return if nothing is receive ? An empty string '' ?
In the other case, if in fact, it is blocking, how can i do to put it as an unblocking function ? I heard about [settimeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) but I don't know if it is actually the right solution.

Answer (score 8):

By default it is blocking. It can be turned into non-blocking via `socket.setblocking(0)` or (equivalently) `socket.settimeout(0)`. In that case if there is nothing to receive it will throw `socket.error` exception.

See the docs:

1. Python2:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking
2. Python3:

   1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking
   2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts