# Breaking out of while True loop

Tags: python, xml, while-loop, break

I have a python script which will parse xml file for serial numbers and will write them to a text file. The problem with the below code is, It is going on infinite loop. If I am adding a break statement some where after logging to a file, It is writing only one serial number. How do I increase the counter, so that the program will exit after writing all the serial numbers.

```
try:
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(65507)
        mylist=data.split('\r')
        url = re.findall('http?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', data)
        print url[0]
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url[0])
        the_page = response.read()

        tree = ET.XML(the_page)
        with open("temp.xml", "w") as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(tree))

        document = parse('temp.xml')
        actors = document.getElementsByTagName("ns0:serialNumber")
        for act in actors:
            for node in act.childNodes:
                if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
                        r = "{}".format(node.data)
                        print r
                        logToFile(str(r))

time.sleep(10)
        s.sendto(msg, ('239.255.255.250', 1900) )

except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the condition for finishing the loop - you need some condition.

Comment: Thank you @ AChanpion -  once all the serials numbers are written to the file..It should exit

Comment: For example, can't you exit `if len(data) == 0` ?

Comment: How do you know when you've finishing reading the serial numbers...

Comment: "will parse xml file" - but it doesnt look like it's parsing a file, it's parsing data from a socket. Where does that socket data come from?

Comment: from a router which I am connected @ Tom Dalton

Comment: Fix the indentation of `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: Well the problem is not with indentation. Where to exit the loop after getting all the serial numbers. - Thank you

Comment: @AChampion - The loop will stop and will not print anything once it gets all the serial numbers. The loop is not exiting

Comment: See @AhmadSiavashi's comment ...

Answer (score 1):

I would normally create a flag so that the while would be

```
while working == True:
```

Then reset the flag at the appropriate time.

This allows you to use the `else` statement to close the text file and output the final results after the while loop is complete. [Else clause on Python while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement).

Note that it is always better to explicitly close open files when finished rather than relying on garbage collection. You should also close the file and output a timeout message in the except logic.

For debugging, you can output a statement at each write to the text file.

Answer (score 0):

If your s.recvfrom(65507) is working correctly it should be an easy fix. Write this code just below your `data, addr = s.recvfrom(65507)`

```
if not data:
    break
```

Comment: It says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Where exactly? Also my answer should make you understand what exactly is the concept here. You should have understood by now.

Answer (score 0):

You open a `UDP` socket and you use `recvfrom` to get data from the socket.
You set a high `timeout` which makes this function a `blocking function`. It means when you start listening on the socket, if no data have been sent from the sender your program will be blocked on that line until either the sender sends something or the `timeout` reaches. In case of `timeout` and no data the function will raise an `Exception`.

I see two options:

- Send something from the sender that indicates the end of stream (the serial numbers in your case).
- Set a small `timeout` then catch the `Exception` and use it to break the loop.

Also, take a look at this question: [socket python : recvfrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166594/socket-python-recvfrom)

Hope it helps.